# Order of execution (field updates and escalation rules)

Tags: field-update, order-of-execution

Salesforce documentation is saying that workflow field updates fire before escalation rules (item 11 and 14) [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

[image]

But it is also saying that field updates fire after Case escalation rules (at the top of the page) [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_field_update_considerations.htm&language=en_US)

[image]

Can someone please clarify this for me?

Thanks!

Comment: If you trigger a workflow with field update, the debug log should reveal which order the actions fire in. Have you tried this?

Comment: @DavinCasey debug logs say that Field Update goes first.